# The system cannot find the file specified.(exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I have the option to add the crystal report viewer to a form, but when I try to make a report, it gives me the error:

> The system cannot find the file specified.(exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)

I've installed it on Win 7 64 bit Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I tried changing the target framework to 4.0 and then back to 4.5 it didn't work. Ive even uninstalled and reinstalled a couple of times still ain't working.

How do I resolve this?